# I accidentally remove the window boot option, how can i restore it

Tags: operating-system, boot

I was trying to install archlinux dual boot with window, when turning off the RAID in system configuration (i currently using BIOS 1.26.0), it removed my window boot option, now i can not boot window, how can i restore the window boot manager ?

I have tried to add the window boot manager from the efi folder to the boot option (it named bootmgr.efi.mui in efi/microsoft folder) but it didn't work

Comment: Restore from backups.